# Variables documentation in Scala

Tags: scala, documentation

I'm new in Scala (I come from Java) and I would like to know how is the correct way to generate documentation for the class variables.

For example, if I have the following code:

```
class MyClass (bar:bar) {

  val foo = bar

  def function {
      ...
      ...
  }
}
```

what's the correct way to create the documentation for the variable `foo` ? Do I just add the comment right before the declaration? Isn't it a bit confusing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javadoc in Scala. But Scala also introduces its own documentation generator called Scaladoc. This is what is used to generate the standard language [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/).

In general, Scaladoc follows similar conventions to Javadoc but introduces new features. You can read more about Scaladoc comments style [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/scaladoc.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between java and scala comments. You can choose any documentation strategy you used in java.

Comment: There is, however, a difference between Javadoc and Scaladoc comments.